# Are there any tricks to Rival Smash?

Tags: super-smash-bros-4

Currently, I'm trying to be as cheap as I can think to be in rival smash: using characters like Bowser and Zelda to keep the rival in the air as much as possible, while taking advantage of their decent offensive capabilities. The most I can seem to get is 20, but Challenge Board 3 has a requirement of 50 kills.

I understand that there is a decent amount of skill required to complete this, but I'm sure there are some characters who naturally do better than others. Is this true, and if so, which characters work well for this encounter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used Captain Falcon and here's why.

He's deceivingly heavier than he looks, and he's got an instant KO in this mode.

Just use -> B to KO the baddies and ignore your rival. He'll be unable to keep up with your score. You also want to stand on one of the two middle platforms to make sure that you'll get a KO from each -> B. Here's a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vRCOSNk7y3k) that basically did the exact same thing that I did if you're having more trouble.

Comment: Thanks! I was at least onto something with the heavier characters being better at this. This was pretty much how I did the 110 KOs in 3 minute smash too, except I used someone else. I'll give this a try, but given that it is reproducible, I'll accept the answer.

Comment: You're welcome. I've yet to see a better way of doing this. If you find one, let me know and I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

In general, you should use a character that has several 1-hit KOs and can survive a decent number of hits from your rival. Heavy characters, therefore, are better generally. Then follow these general ideas:

- Spam your 1-hit KO attacks
- Mostly ignore your rival, but when you can hit your rival safely, do. Mostly, I find this easy to do with an up-smash attack when your rival is on a platform directly above you.
- Use the items when they appear if you can get to them safely (the pow block is especially good for driving up your score since it is multi-use and can knock out multiple opponents at a time).
- Stay alive!

Specifically, I found it very easy to get high scores with Peach. This is mostly because the computer is particularly bad at this challenge with Peach.

- Only a few of your attacks are 1-hit KOs. You will be spamming these while the CPU performs slow, non-1-hit KO attacks.
- Peach has very high survivability even for newer players due to her ability to float long horizontal distances.
- It takes the CPU *forever* to return to the stage when knocked horizontally. The CPU typically exhausts the entire floating air-time of Peach before grabbing the edge, allowing you to rack up the score.